# how to update Real variable based on different scenarios in Modelica?

Tags: initialization, modelica, openmodelica

I built the model below in Modelica, the `Kc` and `Ah` are supposed to update for mode 3 and mode 4, but the simulation results show that `Kc` and `Ah` are always 1 and 0. Where does the error come from, how to update a Real variable in Modelica

```
model LiquidFraction_modify_Q
  parameter Real Bh=2.118;
  parameter Real Bc=18.37;
  parameter Real Tmc=21.56+273.15;
  parameter Real Tmh=22.32+273.15;
  parameter Real vh=2.804;
  parameter Real vc=31.11;

  Real Ah;
  Real Kc;
  Real Kh=1;
  Real Ac=0;
  Boolean heating_pre;
  Real mode;

initial equation 
  heating_pre=true;
  Kc=1;
  Ah=0;

equation 
  if heating_pre then //"previous heating mode"
    if Tair>=Tpcm then
      H=Ah+(Kh-Ah)/(1+exp(-Bh*(Tpcm-Tmh)))^(1/vh);
      dHdT=-(Bh*exp(Bh*(Tmh-Tpcm))*(Ah-Kh))/(vh*(exp(Bh*(Tmh-Tpcm))+1)^(1/vh+1));
      mode=1;
    //"continue heating mode"
    else
      H=Ah+(Kh-Ah)/(1+exp(-Bh*(Tpcm-Tmh)))^(1/vh);
      dHdT=-(Bh*exp(Bh*(Tmh-Tpcm))*(Ah-Kh))/(vh*(exp(Bh*(Tmh-Tpcm))+1)^(1/vh+1));
      mode=2; //"switch heating to cooling mode"
    end if;
  else   //"previously cooling mode"
    if Tair>=Tpcm then
      H= Ac+(Kc-Ac)/(1+exp(-Bc*(Tpcm-Tmc)))^(1/vc);
      dHdT=-(Bc*exp(Bc*(Tmc - Tpcm))*(Ac - Kc))/(vc*(exp(Bc*(Tmc - Tpcm)) + 1)^(1/vc + 1));
      mode=3; //"switch cooling to heating mode"
    else
      H= Ac+(Kc-Ac)/(1+exp(-Bc*(Tpcm-Tmc)))^(1/vc);
      dHdT=-(Bc*exp(Bc*(Tmc - Tpcm))*(Ac - Kc))/(vc*(exp(Bc*(Tmc - Tpcm)) + 1)^(1/vc + 1));
      mode=4; //"continue cooling mode"
    end if;
  end if;

algorithm 
  when {mode>0.5 and mode <1.5} then
    heating_pre:=true;
  end when;
  when {mode>=3.5 and mode <4.5} then
    heating_pre:=false;
  end when;
  when {mode>1.5 and mode <2.5} then
    heating_pre:=false;
    Kc:=(H-Ah)*((1+exp(Bh*Tmh-Bh*Tpcm))^(1/vh))+Ah;
  end when;
  when {mode>=2.5 and mode <3.5} then
    heating_pre:=true;
    Ah:=(H-Kc/((1+exp(-Bc*(Tpcm-Tmc)))^(1/vc)))/(1-1/((1+exp(-Bc*(Tpcm-Tmc)))^(1/vc)));
  end when;
end LiquidFraction_modify_Q;
```

Comment: I also use algorithm when to recalculate Kc and Ah for mode 2 and 3, it is not fully formulated here in the code.

Comment: I have tried to fix you post/code, but there seem to be variables missing (Tair, Tpcm, H, dHdT...). Could you take care?

Comment: Thanks, Tair, Tpcm are input and H, dHdT are output of the model. At every timestep, I want to compare Tair and Tpcm then decide which mode to use for calculating H and dHdT. I also have an algorithm section where I put a “when” function to update Kc and Ah at and do iteration. (sorry that I did not put algorithm section here and I cannot modify the post currently)

Comment: Could you edit the code in the post to make it represent this?

Comment: yes, I add them here,could you please take a look at it? For mode 2 and 3, | will first calculate H, then update Kc or Ah based on a function of H at this instant.

Comment: Your code still does not check. It's easier to help if you provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example